# A basic question about $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

> Let $\Omega$ be an open interval $(-1,1)$. Does there exist $u$ in $L^1(\Omega)$ such that $u$ is not in $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$?

Let $I=(a,b)$ ba an open interval, possibly unbounded.

$W^{1,1}(I)=\left\{ u\in L^{1}\left(I\right):\exists g\in L^{1}\left(I\right)\mathrm{such\; that}\int_{I}u\varphi'=-\int_{I}g\varphi\;\forall\varphi\in C_{c}^{1}\left(I\right)\right\} 
 $

I know that such $u$ exists but I can't write it precisely. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Try to find a $L^1$-function which has no weak derivative.

Comment: $u(x)=1 \forall x \in (0,1)$ and $=-1 \forall x \in (-1,0)$

Comment: And there you go, example found.

Comment: Maybe you should write it as an answer to your own question, so it doesn't remain unsolved.

Comment: It is worth to note that every function $u\in W^{1,1}(I)$ is continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$u(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & x\in\left(0,1\right)\\
-1 & x\in\left(-1,0\right)
\end{cases}$